# How to solve that MySQL salve delays a long time after master?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a MySQL master and slave, but it happens that the slave always stop in the operation `delete from t where cond is TRUE`. No matter how I set the binlog format to MIXED or ROW or build index, all they can not solve the problem. And the table `t` has ten million records. Are there some people know about this?

Comment: Stops why? What's the last SQL error in the slave status? Solve that and you've solved the problem. Insufficient information provided, and off topic.

Comment: @EJP，the slave can not work any more， it just keep the state and Exec_Master_Log_Pos doesn't move.

Comment: Let's clarify this: *"the slave always stop"*.  When a slave *stops*, the value of `Slave_SQL_Running` in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` changes to `No`.  It sounds like you are trying to say that your slave is not actually stopping, but *appears to stall* and `Seconds_Behind_Master` is increasing.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, yeah, that is right.